# Dojo treegrid runs fine locally, but not on remote server

Tags: datagrid, dojo, treegrid

Using dojo's TreeGrid (v. 1.9.0) served by my local machine (mvc.net) the grid loads fine with my sample, hard-coded data.  However, when served from a remote machine, I get the un-debuggable "Sorry, an error occurred".

Breakpoints within my formatters are not even hit, suggesting the problem does not lie with any unloaded dependencies within a formatter.  This fails not only on initial startup, but also if at runtime I try to reload the model using .setModel(myNewModel) after everything has definitely loaded.  I have the firebug flag set in the dojo config object, and no informative warnings or errors are showing up in firefox...just that annoying and useless message in the grid itself.

Answer (score 1):

The `Sorry, an error occurred message` is a result of a problem with your store and usually the data you are putting into the store.

The message is shown in `DataGrid._onFetchError` and `TreeGrid` mixes in the `DataGrid`.

You can

- put a break point on the query engine of what ever store you are using,
- analyze the data being passed into the store

Comment: The problem seemed to be caused by errors thrown in other .js files, which for some reason the local version could ignore, but the remote version could not.  I suspect a module timing issue.  Fixing the unrelated errors fixed the TreeGrid issue.  Ahhh dojo....